# Cannot use os.system with 'æ', 'ø' or 'å'

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.system

I'm trying to execute a .vbs script from my python script using `os.system()`.

It's like this

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
os.system('cscript myVbsScript.vbs -i "This is a test" "1000" "æøå"')
```

"æøå" is not passed correctly.

When using:

```
os.system(u'cscript myVbsScript.vbs -i "This is a test" "1000" "æøå"')
```

I get the error:

```
os.system(u'cscript myVbsScript.vbs 10000 "This is a test" "1000" "æøå"')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 55-57: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

When I'm not trying to use "æøå" in `os.system` then it works like a charm - so I am afraid that the problem is with `os.system`.

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: Do you have to use Python 2.7? This error would not happen in 3.x.

Comment: Yes - I have to use Python 2.7.

Declaring the string as unicode does not solve my problem - as I also wrote in my post.

Comment: I suggest you to read this article so when you find this kind of bug you understand how to solve it: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

You should encode your string (updated encoding type):

```
os.system(u'cscript myVbsScript.vbs -i "This is a test" "1000" "æøå"'.encode("iso-8859-1"))
```

Comment: UTF-8 may not be the correct encoding though, since this is Windows. MBCS possibly, or something else altogether.

Comment: That gives me the error:
`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file D:\sandbox\keybordEmulator\test.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

Comment: Because apparently you removed the `# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-` -- the error message tells you this. This is another thing which Python 3 handles by simply declaring that UTF-8 is the default encoding for scripts. (Again, we have to assume that your text is *actually* UTF-8; there is no evidence to the contrary, but sometimes people blindly apply these things without understanding what they mean.)

Comment: @AKX you were right! I had to use the the following:
`os.system(u'cscript myVbsScript.vbs -i "This is a test" "1000" "æøå"'.encode("iso-8859-1"))`

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*-
import os
os.system(u'cscript myVbsScript.vbs -i "This is a test" "1000" "æøå"'.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

The .vbs-script couldn't read the utf-8 encode.